# Transpose Query.. I need to process with 1.5 Million records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Need a help

ACTUAL TABLE

```
COL1  COL2
A     1,2,3,4
```

i need to convert by

```
COL1   COL2
A       1
A       2
A       3
A       4
```

Comment: You seem to have mistaken the purpose of this site; we are not www.rent-a-coder.com

Answer (score 1):

Number of Possible rows is huge!! Oops.. May be a bad approach to do this.

```
SELECT col1,REGEXP_SUBSTR (col2,,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) txt
  FROM my_table
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (col2,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   AND PRIOR col2 = col2
   AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

Another Version FRom [Here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/184666/)

```
SELECT col1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.col2, '([^,])+', 1, t2.COLUMN_VALUE)
FROM my_table t1 CROSS JOIN
            TABLE
            (
                CAST
                (
                    MULTISET
                    (
                        SELECT LEVEL
                        FROM DUAL 
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t1.colval, '([^,])+')
                    )
                    AS SYS.odciNumberList
                )
            ) t2;
```